# Populate Multicolumn Listview using my custom class object - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

how can i populate / Inflate list view using my array list of custom objects

for example

```
    class Student{
        private int id;
        private int name;
        private int age;
    }
//for example
ArrayList<Student> myListItems  = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

my goal is to print on screen like

-------- id -------- Name -------- Age

-------- 1 -------- bla bla -------- 90
.
.
.

so on...
Please suggest me any easy and optimized way to do this

Comment: See [Using lists in Android (ListView) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/support.html) example

Comment: isnt it gridview will work?

Comment: Logic is same just use GridView instead of ListView in code and also in xml

Comment: If you don't want a ListView element, you can implement 3 TextView elements (horizontal) with a scrolling bar. But this is not common usage, I believe. Otherwise I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather common question for implementing a Listview. I can give you one good example. Look at the code extending the `ArrayAdapter` and the `ViewHolder` containing the data in `getView` method, your example would be the data in Student. 
Link at [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

I think this web page is good because there are some explanations. Good luck and have fun. Keep us posted.